# Is working for ad-based companies Halal?

Tags: halal-haram

Is it halal to work for companies like Facebook/Google who provide some beneficial service (especially Google) but their main revenue source is from advertisement?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it halal to work for companies like Facebook/Google who provide some beneficial service (especially Google) but their main revenue source is from advertisement?

Like every other other business, it depends on the nature of the business itself.

Here it depends on what is being advertised. Given that Google and Facebook have both facilitated an advertising model which has turned the world awash in advertising dross; that the industry itself has facilitated hardcore online porn; that it has also facilitated online surveillance to the extent that a parliamentry report has accused facebook of being run (I don't recall the exact wording), like a bunch of mafia gangsters; I'd consider it at best, mokru.

The industry is awash in cash - they could have done a much better job of moderating and gate-keeping.

For example, had Mark Zuckerberg, understood that they weren't a technology firm - whatever this means - but a massively parallel publishing firm - and therefore should have looked towards the ethics in the publishing world, much of the idiocy now seen could have been avoided; but he took, a laissez-faire approach; mostly I expect, it kepts cost down - and - of course - profits up. He never really understood what it meant to offer neo-nazis, fascists and sadists a publishing platform, until it was much too late.

There was a recent newspaper article, for example, that Facebook was hiring another 1,000 additional staff to help with moderating their content; supposing a salary of £100,000 p/a this works out to be £100 million per year; this is peanuts given what they earn in revenue - and their lack of foresight.

Comment: I would like to add. If the company itself is not a huge multinational absorbing people's wealth or destroying their health, then we should look towards other issues, such as, do the ads themselves contain music, obscenity, women, etc.

Comment: @el flea: If you look at what I wrote you will see I had written: 'advertising dross; that the industry itself has facilitated hardcore online porn; that it has also facilitated online surveillance to the extent that a parliamentry report has accused facebook of being run (I don't recall the exact wording), like a bunch of mafia gangsters;'

Comment: Ah I see. The language was a bit confusing so I missed it.

Comment: @el flea: How could you have seen it when you just skim-read the answer?